# Search attributes of selected users in CN

Tags: php, ldap

In my LDAP configuration I have a script that gets a couple of attributes from all users and displays this on a page.

```
$dn = "cn=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com;
$sr = ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filter, $justthese);
$result = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
```

Of course I know which users are in a certain group (CN). What I want to do is getting the same attributes just from these users instead of from everyone.

I thought that just changing $dn would be sufficient, like this:

```
$dn = "cn=examplegroup,cn=groups,dc=mydomain,dc=com";
```

This gives no results however. Anyone knows what's the most efficient solution for this problem? We have 1500+ users in the database, so efficiency is really important.

Comment: If you only want users from the examplegroup, you can change the filter to include a membership attribute. If you want all groups under cn=groups, change the subtree for the search to cn=groups,dc=mydomain,dc=com.

Comment: This works indeed, but in this case ldap_search opens the entire directory cn=users, and scans every entry for his memberof attributes. Wouldn't there be a way to just search in one group like cn=examplegroup,cn=groups,dc=mydomain,dc=com?
Like I said, I'd like to find optimal performance :)

Comment: Can you change the base entry for your search to cn=examplegroup,cn=groups,dc=mydomain,dc=com?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I already tried that, like I posted in my question, or do you mean something different?

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you try using ldapsearch? eg. ldapsearch -h ds -p port -D "cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com" -W -b "cn=examplegroup,cn=groups,dc=mydomain,dc=com" filter. Try to get results that way and then replicate with php?

Comment: Hi Ryan, sorry I'm not familiar with LDAP via Terminal. Which commands need to be executed before typing in your suggestion?